# No image view of Facebook?

Tags: facebook

When I browse Facebook feed, all the images take up too much space.
I think it would be better (for me) if I can see only texts, or at least with much smaller images.
Is there an alternative interface of Facebook for text only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a Facebook lite version (not text only but saves some data usage), but it was discontinued. The mobile version would be the best alternative.

There are some ways to save mobile data on the mobile web browser.
https://www.browsertouse.com/blog/12843/save-mobile-data-chrome-android